# compare two files in Google Drive and see if one is an exact copy of the other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have two files in a Google Drive. They may or may not be copies of each other. The file names have changed, and the file URLs are obviously different.

How can I check if the files are duplicates?

If they were files on my computer, I'd take hashes of the files. But there doesn't seem to be a way to do that in Google Drive.

Comment: If I make a copy of a file on my computer, a PDF, a docx, whatever, then the hashes will be the same, no? I mean, so far, in all my tests they have been.

Comment: Regarding file hashing, it is possible to calculate file hashes using Google Apps Script. The Utilities class in Apps Script provides a method called [`computeDigest()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value) that enables you to calculate the hash of a given file. You can utilize this method to compute the file hash and compare it between files. Have you come across this functionality before?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 I have seen that but how do you use that to compute the digest of a Google Drive file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, how about checking the value of `md5Checksum`? When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```js
function checkFiles_(f, checks = ["md5Checksum", "sha1Checksum", "sha256Checksum"]) {
  files = f.map(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id));
  const fields = [...checks, "id"].join(",");
  const o = files.reduce((o, f) => {
    const mimeType = f.getMimeType();
    if (["FOLDR", "SHORTCUT"].some(m => mimeType == MimeType[m])) {
      throw new Error("Folders cannot be checked.");
    }
    let obj;
    if (mimeType.includes("application/vnd.google-apps")) {
      const name = f.getName();
      f.setName("temp");
      Utilities.sleep(2000);
      obj = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.PDF }, f.getBlob(), { supportsAllDrives: true, fields });
      f.setName(name);
      Drive.Files.remove(obj.id); // If an error occurs, please use DriveApp.getFileById(obj.id).setTrashed(true);
    } else {
      obj = Drive.Files.get(f.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true, fields });
    }
    checks.forEach(e => o[e] = o[e] ? [...o[e], obj[e]] : [obj[e]]);
    return o;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(o).every(e => [...new Set(e)].length == 1);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const file1 = "###fileId1###"; // Please set your file ID of file 1.
  const file2 = "###fileId2###"; // Please set your file ID of file 2.

  const check = checkFiles_([file1, file2], ["md5Checksum"]);
  const res = `"${file1}" and "${file2}" are${check ? " " : " not "}the same data.`;
  console.log(res)
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of `md5Checksum` of both files are compared. When the values of `md5Checksum` is the same, `check` returns `true`.
- This script cannot check the folder. Please be careful about this.
- When the file is Google Docs (Documents, Spreadsheets, Slides, and so on) file, the file is converted to PDF data, and retrieves the value of `md5Checksum`.
- As additional information, in this sample script, the value of `md5Checksum` is checked. Recently, `sha1Checksum` and `sha256Checksum` have been added. Of course, these values can be used for checking. If you want to use `sha1Checksum` or `sha256Checksum`, please modify `md5Checksum` to `sha1Checksum` or `sha256Checksum`, and also include `fields` of `sha1Checksum` or `sha256Checksum` to the methods of Drive API. Because the values of `sha1Checksum` and `sha256Checksum` are not included in the returned values as the default. Please be careful about this.
- Of course, the values of `sha1Checksum` and `sha256Checksum` can be calculated using `Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, bytes)` and `Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, bytes)`. But, in this case, it depends on the file size. For example, when the file size is more than 50 MB, an error like `exceeds the maximum file size.` occurs. Please be careful about this. And also, the process cost becomes high. For example, when I tested a file with 20 MB, the processing time for calculating `sha256Checksum` is about 15 seconds. On the other hand, when `sha256Checksum` is directly retrieved by Drive API, it is about 0.1 seconds.
- As another sample script, when you want to compare the values of "md5Checksum", "sha1Checksum", "sha256Checksum", how about the following sample script?

  ```js
  function myFunction2() {
    const file1 = "###fileId1###"; // Please set your file ID of file 1.
    const file2 = "###fileId2###"; // Please set your file ID of file 2.

    const checks = ["md5Checksum", "sha1Checksum", "sha256Checksum"];
    const fields = [...checks, "id"].join(",");
    const files = [file1, file2].map(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id));
    const o = files.reduce((o, f) => {
      const mimeType = f.getMimeType();
      if (mimeType == MimeType.FOLDR) {
        throw new Error("Folders cannot be checked.");
      }
      let obj;
      if (mimeType.includes("application/vnd.google-apps")) {
        obj = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.PDF }, f.getBlob(), { supportsAllDrives: true, fields });
        Drive.Files.remove(obj.id); // If an error occurs, please use DriveApp.getFileById(obj.id).setTrashed(true);
      } else {
        obj = Drive.Files.get(f.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true, fields });
      }
      checks.forEach(e => o[e] = o[e] ? [...o[e], obj[e]] : [obj[e]]);
      return o;
    }, {});
    const check = Object.values(o).every(e => [...new Set(e)].length == 1);
    const res = `"${file1}" and "${file2}" are${check ? " " : " not "}the same data.`;
    console.log(res)
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. So, this script might be required to be modified by your actual situation. Please be careful about this. For example, the above sample scripts cannot use folders, shortcuts, and so on.

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/get)

Comment: This doesn't work well for Google Drive files. For example, if I create a Google Doc, then make a copy of it, and then I try this script -- it'll say the files are not the same.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Thank you for replying. From your reply, I noticed that your files include Google Documents. So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. In this modified script, when I tested your situation of `For example, if I create a Google Doc, then make a copy of it, and then I try this script -- it'll say the files are not the same.`, those were the same files.

Comment: Ah. I see. You're setting temp name to file, inserting as PDF, and comparing PDF? Nice. Thank you!

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Thank you for replying. About `You're setting temp name to file, inserting as PDF, and comparing PDF?`, it's yes. I'm worried that the filename might be included in the PDF. So, before the Google Docs file is converted to PDF, I set the same filename. By the way, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.